# Kafka JDBC Sink Connector compatibly works with PostgreSQL 12?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm looking for the documentation mentioned the compatible databases that Kafka JDBC Sink Connector (developed by Confluent) is working well with. However, I cannot see any documentations mention that one.

I'm seeing the insertion performance issue after upgrading our database to Postgres 12 from Postgres 9.5. Wondering if that's caused by the current JDBC Connector version we're using or any other things.

Please give me your advice.

Comment: What's version of Kafka JDBC Sink Connector do you use?

Comment: We're using Confluent 5.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to infer what databases are supported from the source code that specifies what driver versions are used

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/blob/master/pom.xml#L59

You can also look at the dialects available

https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/tree/master/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/jdbc/dialect